# Sum price based on date and print based on clubs in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and those are football and football assets.

The **Football** looks like:-

```
id | pair | name | date | price | sell | fetched
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6    |  luca-antonelli  | Luca Antonelli | 2018-12-20 04:57:36 | 0.50 | 0.47 | 1
7    |  luca-antonelli  | Luca Antonelli | 2018-09-06 12:39:58 | 0.65 | 0.52 | 1
8    |  luca-antonelli  | Luca Antonelli | 2018-10-15 16:45:28 | 0.59 | 0.49 | 1
9    |  ryan-fraser     | Ryan Fraser    | 2018-03-28 08:56:57 | 5.51 | 0.47 | 1
10   |  ryan-fraser     | Ryan Fraser    | 2018-04-20 06:19:07 | 7.28 | 0.49 | 1
11   |  jordon-ibe      | Jordon Ibe     | 2018-10-14 22:52:58 | 11.23 | 0.17 | 1
12   |  jordon-ibe      | Jordon Ibe     | 2018-11-25 19:37:26 | 2.31 | 0.29 | 1
```

So you can see there are three rows so from here it will pick the price based on date
The **football assets** looks like:-

```
    id | pair | Club
   -----------------------------------
    86 |  luca-antonelli  | Liverpool
    87 |  ryan-fraser     | Liverpool
    88 |  jordon-ibe      | Liverpool
```

So the club liverpool has 3 players. If you look into the football table you will see they have different prices. So it will pick the latest price based on datetime for each player and then add it up. pair is the common column between two tables. So there are many records like this. I want to sum the price of all the players of that club but the price will be the latest. price will take it from **date** column from **football** table. The output looks like:-

```
club | price
------------------
Liverpool | 28.07
```

The query I have tried is:-

```
SELECT club, SUM(price) as price from football JOIN football_assets ON football_assets.pair = football.pair WHERE club IN ('Paris Saint-Germain', 'Lille', 'Lyon')
```

One player have many prices but I want only their latest price to be summed. The above query is summing all the prices. I want that optimization.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show more rows for better clarity. Also, what do you mean by `latest price to be summed`? If latest price is only 1 row in your table, what is the need of summing?

Comment: @vivek_23 There are way more than one row. I just gave an example.

Comment: @vivek_23 I have updated the code please check and let me know.

Comment: The output  `28.07` is sum of all prices. So, where is only latest considered?

Comment: @vivek_23 that's the mistake It's adding all the prices instead of the latest price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below by using subquery

```
select fa.club,sum(a.price) as price from

  (
  select f.* football f
   where f.date=(select max(date) from football f1 where f1.pair=f.pair)
  ) a join  footballassets fa on a.pair=fa.pair
  group by fa.club
```

By using correlated subquery i pick all the latest price then used join with assets table getting the club

Comment: @AlekStephanok can you please paste here that error